# Targeting a query in Mongo to find and email nested in an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to do a query for an endpoint in my Node/Express & Mongo/Mongoose API.

Here is a representation of the document/schema I'm trying to query:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59474bc3478604a75e1980e2"),
  "initial" : "D",
  "last_name" : "Spitz",
  "first_name" : "Chris",
  "owner_id" : "59474b92478604a75e1980e1",
  "contacts" : [
    {
      "last_name" : "Jones",
      "first_name" : "Tom",
      "_id" : ObjectId("5947fd928389ffb393fbc310"),
      "addresses" : [ ],
      "phones" : [ ],
      "emails" : [
        {
          "email_type" : "home",
          "email_address" : "runner@running.com",
          "_id" : ObjectId("5947fd928389ffb393fbc311")
        },
        {
          "email_type" : "home",
          "email_address" : "jake@samsonite.com",
          "_id" : ObjectId("5947ff9ed8fa7cb4c781acc9")
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "last_name" : "Smith",
      "first_name" : "Linda",
      "_id" : ObjectId("5947ff9ed8fa7cb4c781acc8"),
      "addresses" : [ ],
      "phones" : [ ],
      "emails" : [
        {
          "email_type" : "home",
          "email_address" : "chris@chrisnakea.com",
          "_id" : ObjectId("5947ff9ed8fa7cb4c781acc9")
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to check if an email exists in the "contacts.email" array of the document.

Here is the way I'm checking (based on the whey it the item is nested in the schema above):

```
  Profile.find({'contacts.emails.email_address':req.body.invited_email}, function(err, profile){
    if(err)
      console.log('Error in looking for profile.');
    if(profile.contacts.emails.email_address !== null){
      console.log('Found contact: ' + profile.contacts.emails.email_address);
    } else {
      console.log('Contact does not exist');
    }
  })
```

But for some reason I'm getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined" error in the console when testing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Because it's inside an array. You don't need to check in code as the query will do that for you and will only return results when the email is actually "found". So the only check you need is on the "length" of results. `if ( profile.length > 0 ) { console.log('Found contact:' + req.body.invited_email); } else { `. Save yourself the pain of learning how to traverse arrays here, and save that for another day.

Comment: Probably should `findOne()` as well, since `.find()` returns you an array as well, where as `.findOne()` is a single object. But you still would need to traverse AND filter the array to extract the value. Just accept that the "query" did the job and return the "input" in confirmation if you really must.

Comment: Hi Guys, I don't know if that solves my problem. The goal is to check and see if a specific email exists within the Profile.Contacts[]. Just checking the length of the Profile that I already know exists isn't what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes it is. You are misunderstanding. You check the length of the "array" returned in the query response. If nothing matched then it's `0`. Read it all again.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thanks!